# Ubuntu brightness indicator stops working upon laptop open/close

Tags: 14.04, suspend, intel-graphics, brightness, macbook-air

So I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a 2011 edition MacAir, and I had the common problem of being stuck with either full screen brightess or pure darkness, with no options in between.

I installed Brightness Indicator to fix this, which worked like a charm and allowed me to adjust the brightness in small increments. Interestingly, though, it stops working if I open and close the lid (that's suspend, right?), and I'm back to square one with either full or no brightness. But if I reboot, the indicator works again.

I have tried a few fixes, most notably the one [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/fix-brightness-getting-reset-to-very.html), though it's not *exactly* the problem I'm having. I also tried [this](http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/), to no avail.

If it helps, `ls /sys/class/backlight` gives `acpi_video0` and `intel_backlight`.

Here is the output of `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt4'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b ro quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-43-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-43-generic-advanced-614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-43-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b ro quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-43-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-43-generic-recovery-614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-43-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b ro recovery nomodeset quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-43-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-advanced-614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b ro quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-32-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-32-generic-recovery-614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt4 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt4  614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=614738a7-a951-4c02-8051-db3c7901525b ro recovery nomodeset quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

And here is `lspci | grep VGA`:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem too. Simply open `/etc/default/grub.cfg` file as root and find the line which says something like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="............"
```

And paste these lines into the double quotes:

```
acpi_osi= vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 $([ -x /usr/sbin/rhcrashkernel-param ] && /usr/sbin/rhcrashkernel-param || :) rd.luks=0 rd.lvm=0 rd.md=0 rd.dm=0
```

and run:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Changes take place at reboot.

**Edit :**

Solution 2 :

If it is not exist, create the directory /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ using :

`sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`

and copy paste the following into the terminal :

```
echo -e ' Section "Device"\n\tIdentifier  "Intel Graphics"\n\tDriver      "intel"\n\tBusID       "PCI:0:2:0"\n\tOption      "Backlight"       "intel_backlight"\n EndSection' | sudo tee /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

Restart the X session or reboot and see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: That didn't work for me, although my specs were a little different. I didn't have an `/etc/default/grub.cfg`, but I did have `/etc/default/grub`, which seemed like the right file. Here is the important line, as well as the one above it:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`                                    `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Likewise, I didn't have `grub2-mkconfig`, so I ran `grub-mkconfig`. Problem persists, even with reboot :-(

Comment: Answer updated :)

Comment: Still didn't work! :(

Comment: Can you please update the question with output  of `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: You do not have the proper graphic card drivers. Thoroughly look in `lspci` and see if there's another graphics related entry. Try installing drivers for that specific graphic card.

Answer (score 0):

Instructions are provided here for fixing Brightness issues in Ubuntu 14.04: http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/

Which apparently is very common in Ubuntu (brightness issues).

Comment: I already tried that as well; no luck